# Is it safe to run 'create table ...' multiple times?

Tags: sqlite

I have a parser that parses  XML file into SQLite database, and the current implementation generates the 'create table xyz ...' even the table is already existed.

- Is this OK? I mean, is this OK to run 'create table' even when the table exists in db?
- If not, is there easy way to check the names of tables (and its contents) that SQLite db has?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are searching for is [CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) and the FAQ entry [How do I list all tables/indices contained in an SQLite database](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7).

Creating a table without the "IF NOT EXISTS" option will lead to an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can `DROP TABLE` before `CREATE TABLE`, you can safety `DROP TABLE` who don't exists then you don't must checking for `TABLE` existence before `DROP`.

Comment: DROP TABLE can be combined with the 'IF EXISTS' clause as well to prevent an error.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite has a "IF NOT EXISTS" clause so that you can throw a "CREATE TABLE" at the database and it will ignore it if it already exists.  For example:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable ( id INTEGER );

The URL to the documentation about this is at: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html